# Explain this SQL query showing the list of databases using a variable

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone explain how this SQL query works? I have been trying to figure it out but cannot get the logic behind this query.

```
select (@a) 
from ( SELECT (@a :="")
             ,(select (@a) 
               from information_schema.schemata 
               where (@a) in (@a := concat(@a, schema_name, '<br>'))
               )
     ) a
```

Comment: It is NOT an SQL injection. It's just SQL

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to learn SQL injection so included injection in the flow.

Comment: Well, what is the result?

Comment: It outputs every databases name(schema_name) from information_schema.schemata.

Comment: "I...included injection in the flow" where is the injection here, in your opinion? It's just SQL. Injection is where SQL is generated using some other code (e.g. PHP or C#) and that code allows arbitrary content from variables (i.e. SQL which was not intended) to be inserted into the generated SQL string without checking it. You say you don't understand the query, but then also say you "included injection in the flow"...so does that mean you changed something? What did the original look like? What result did you expect from it (if not the result you described above)?

Comment: I meant I included the word "injection" in the flow. By the way, removing it for convenience.  Thanks.

Comment: For reference, I found the above SQL query in a site I had browsed to know more about SQL injection. The above query outputs database names but I don't understand how is it working with the variable.

Comment: I feel his question is very much straight forward. Anybody who runs this query on mysql will see the output.  OP just needs an explanation of how it works!. Why downvotes? care to explain?

Comment: @Akhil look at the revision history. Originally the question appeared to be about how SQL injection attacks were related to the query, which turned out to be a misunderstanding (see comments above). This made the question confusing. It's much more straightforward now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    @a -- Final Result (3)
        FROM 
        ( 
             SELECT (@a :="") -- Resetting the variable after each run, (1)
            (
                SELECT @a -- Does really nothing. This can be anything 
                    FROM information_schema.schemata 
                        WHERE (@a) IN (@a := CONCAT(@a, schema_name, '<br>')) -- This will be executed for each row. But none of the rows will match. At the end, @a will have the desired output  (2)
            )
    ) a
```

For more clarity, run `SELECT * from information_schema.schemata` and see the output

(1), (2), (3) indicates the execution priority

If we split the query, this is what happens as given below

```
 SET @a = "";

 SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE (@a) IN (@a := CONCAT(@a, schema_name, '<br>'));

 SELECT @a;
```

**EDIT : 
Question :** how will the variable "a" have desired output if none of the rows match?

Let us take a small query `select * from mytable where (`**somecondition**`)`
If `mytable` has 10 records and `somecondition` does not use any indexes, then `somecondition` will be execute 10 times. Based on each execution, if the result is true/1 then that row will be displayed. This is the simple theory of sql `select` statements.

Now you may replace `somecondition` with `(@a) IN (@a := CONCAT(@a, schema_name, '<br>'))`, you will get the answer

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. You explained quite well.

Comment: I am glad I helped!

Comment: Can you explain how will the variable "a" have desired output if none of the rows match? Also, how do you determine the execution priority of the query?

Comment: @Akash, I have updated my answer with more elaboration